# Converting CSS Styles Component to Tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I need to convert the following styled component to inline Tailwind CSS (like <div class = "..."). Couldn't get much help from the documentation:

```
@media (hover: hover) {
    &:hover {
      background-color: #eeeeee;
      color: black;

      & svg path {
        transition: fill 0.5s ease;
        fill: black;
      }
    }
  }
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a mixture of [arbitrary variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-variants) and [arbitrary values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values) like:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div class="
  [@media(hover:hover)]:hover:bg-[#eeeeee]
  [@media(hover:hover)]:hover:text-black
  [@media(hover:hover)]:[&_svg_path]:hover:transition-[fill]
  [@media(hover:hover)]:[&_svg_path]:hover:duration-500
  [@media(hover:hover)]:[&_svg_path]:hover:ease-[ease]
  [@media(hover:hover)]:[&_svg_path]:hover:fill-black
">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" width="50" height="50">
    <path d="M0 0H50V50H0z" fill="red"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

You could then consider [refactoring the arbitrary variants to custom variants via a plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#adding-variants) and [adding the arbitrary values as theme values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme).